# Where do we ask questions that are open-ended?

Tags: discussion

If I am tinkering with an idea, and am curious if people have any thoughts on it, where can I ask about it? The normal Math Stack Exchange is for factual, answerable questions, so I feel like that isn't the place for it. Also, I could put it in Reddit, but Reddit doesn't have LaTeX and doesn't feel like the right spot either.

And now that I've written this post, one of the possible tags is "discussion", so perhaps this is the correct place for my question itself, rather than only being the place for questions about the Math Stack Exchange Channel? I'm not sure.

Here is an example. I want to define a measure-theoretic limit by saying

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$

iff

$\forall B_\epsilon(L), \exists B_\delta(c) , \mu(B_\delta \setminus f^{-1}(B_\epsilon)) = 0$

Comment: Perhaps a [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com) is appropriate?  Reputation 50 is needed to "speak" in a chatroom, but you seem to have that.

Comment: r/Math. There are some really smart people there.

Comment: Maybe not exactly the same, but these questions seem a bit related: [What are some alternatives to math.stackexchange where discussions are allowed?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34331), [Looking for other math forums for more "soft" discussions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32572), [What is a good forum for math discussion?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25878) (You can probably find a few more similar questions posted here on [math.meta.se].)

Comment: In any event, math.meta is definitely not an appropriate place for the question about measure-theoretic limits.